# Picture on full width screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to cover the image on of my page the full width of the screen. (so not the whole screen but only the width) and if possible I would also like if the image shrinks if the screen gets smaller. I never did this before so i don't really know how I can make this? Can anybody help me?

[this is how my page currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8AnZ.jpg)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: #ADF1F5;
}

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Anouk {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}

#Anouk img{
    display: block;
}

#header {
    height: 80px;
    background: #000000;
}

li {
 display: block;
    float: left;
}

li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
 height: 80px;
}

#contact {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="Anouk">
  <img src="logo/Hout.png" width="1000px" alt="Logo" />
</div>
<div id="header">
  <div id="menu">
    <!--Home-->
    <li id="home">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="Iconen/Home.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Home2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Home.png'" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--Over Mij-->
    <li id="over">
      <a href="over.html">
        <img src="Iconen/Over.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Over2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Over.png'" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--Portfolio-->
    <li id="portfolio">
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        <img src="Iconen/Portfolio.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Portfolio2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Portfolio.png'" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--Contact-->
    <li id="contact">
      <a href="contact.html">
        <img src="Iconen/Contact.png" height="80px" alt="home" onmouseover="this.src='Iconen/Contact2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Iconen/Contact.png'" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your img to width="100%" or set a css class on the image for whatever %.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to have been of some help

Answer (score 0):

And you need to add:

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

To The body because some Browsers (like chrome) are having a standard margin and padding.
PS: I wanted to comment but I cant because my Reputation is to low :(

Comment: That won't make an image 100% width of a screen on various viewport sizes. From the OPs screenshot the default margin that browsers apply does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: I know this was just a supplement to Hexana's answer :D

Comment: Answers are not comments. Please refrain from doing so until you have enough rep to comment. Doing so will likely get you downvotes which will hurt your rep.

Comment: But Why I cant give a tipp to him just because I dont have enough rep.? Thats crazy (sry)

Comment: No, it's not crazy. Why? Because _**your tip is NOT AN ANSWER to the question**_. If it was a comment to the answer or to the question everything would be in its proper place. Your _"tip"_ is currently an answer, which it is not. You only need `50` rep to comment. As you gain more rep you are allowed more responsibility. See [Can I put my comment in an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead#answer-214174).